# Continue scrolling after last slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have a Slider in which I want when the slider hits the last slide it will continue to scroll down the page ?

Please see this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/richardv/pen/OoxVMQ):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});

const slider = $(".customer-logos");


slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if  (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
   $(this).slick('slickNext'); 

  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev')
  }
}));
```

Comment: Do you want to stop continue scrolling? Please clear your requirement.

Comment: @seAction I want it to pause scrolling when it his the HTML section, and when it scrolls to the last slide in the section, I want it to continue scrolling down the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by checking if it's the last silde then do not prevent default action wich will trigger scroll on page , other wise preventDefault action and slide the slider :

```
 if (slideCount - totalSildeToShow == currentIndex)
      return;
```

See below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.customer-logos').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 1500,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4
      }
    }, {
      breakpoint: 520,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    }]
  });
});

const slider = $(".customer-logos");


slider.on('wheel', (function(e) {

  var slideCount = $(this)[0].slick["slideCount"];
  var currentIndex = $(this).slick("slickCurrentSlide");
  var totalSildeToShow =  $(this)[0].slick.options["slidesToShow"];

  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');

  } else {
    if (slideCount - totalSildeToShow == currentIndex)
      return;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).slick('slickNext')
  }
}));
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
  float: right;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: block;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Our Partners</h2>
  <section class="customer-logos slider">
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>
  </section>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Is there anyway this can work on reverse? Currently when the user scrolls back up the website the slider just stays in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway this can work on reverse? Currently when the user scrolls back up the website the slider just stays in the loop...

I know that it's old question, but I found solution like that:

```js
if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
  if (currentIndex === 0) 
    return;

  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).slick('slickPrev');
} else {
  if (slideCount - totalSildeToShow === currentIndex)
    return;

  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).slick('slickNext');
}
```